# How to open drawer with a horizontal swipe only on a specific linear layout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, drawerlayout, drawer

I have a very simple activity with a drawer and two linear layouts.
I need to implement: if we swipe horizontally right on any place of the buttom layout, it will open the drawer (same as in Telegram app). But it should not open it on the top layout, because it contains a pager.

Could you please help how to implement it?

[image]

Comment: post your layout xml also

Answer (score 0):

Make drawer layout as parent layout. put your view inside drawer layout.

```
<!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

//Your view here

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout >
```

Comment: My DrawerLayout is already root container for all other views.